# How to install Anaconda by package control in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublime-anaconda

It's showing me

> There are no packages available for installation.

what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come to mind:

1) You could already have it installed

or

2) You are not opening the "Install" option in the package manager.
"Command + P" opens your package manager but you still need to "access" the Install option.